# How to extract the value of a given cell?

Tags: python, excel, xlrd

I want to get the value of a given cell, but my code gives me following error:

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'value'.

How can I modify it to get the value and not the position of the cell?

```
data = xl_rowcol_to_cell(row+2,col+3)
datavalue = data.value
print datavalue
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To access the value for a specific cell you would use:

`value = worksheet.cell(row, column)`